# Storing multiple mp3 and mp4 files in 1 BLOB in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, blob, mp3, mp4

I am trying to determine a strategy for storing multiple mp3 and mp4 files in 1 blob in SQL Server. Each blob will be less than 10 MB in size and will not be modified once stored. I have read about the advantages of using a file system to store the files rather than in the database and have determined that this is not the path we'd like to take due to security issues.

I have several basic questions. Is it possible to store these multiple files in a single blob? How are the files determined to be distinct files within a blob in DB storage? I.e., is there a file separator delimiter? How will the files be parsed/played by an mp3 player?

Comment: Just don't do this. Storing them in the database is one thing, but forcing multiple pieces of data into a single column violates 1NF and will cause you nothing but anguish. Store each file in its own row.

Comment: You are going to have a challenge on your hands here though with mp3s. You will have to extract the blob from the database, then write it to a file so it will be an mp3, then stream it or send it to wherever it needs to go. I would suggest looking harder into security and storing them as a file. Will save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: You could store both in a single blob but it would be completely up to you to separate the bits afterward (e.g. you would need to store the length of each separately). Players would not understand the mixed stream natively. This is the same problem as if you were store both in a single file. Why not store in separate blobs?

Comment: Sean Lange & @Dan Guzman: thanks for your replies. The reason to not store in separate blobs is that a blob contains files that are legs of 1 phone call (having 1 conn id), with the files corresponding to transfers to different agents or to an mp4 agent screen recording. Regarding the playing of the mp3 files, won't the file headers contain the necessary information for a player to use an mp3 or mp4 codec to play the contents?

Comment: Yes but when you store them in a single column it is not longer two files. Just don't do this. It is awful beyond comprehension. Delimited strings in a database are a total nightmare, doing this with files is taking it to a whole new level of insanity. If you have a series of mp3 files all related to the same call you should consider storing each piece separately with a sequence number to indicate the order and a foreign key to whatever the call is related to. Or if need them to be seamless then you should record your mp3 files as a single one with all the segments.